# How to find limit of $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{N}^{e^N} xe^{-x^{2017}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{N}^{e^N} xe^{-x^{2017}}dx$$

I know limits for improper integrals of the form: 
  $$\int_{a}^b f(x)dx$$ where $b \to \infty$.

But this appears to be of the form: $$\int_{\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$$

Comment: Yes and it is $0$ because the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x^{2017}}dx$ converges.

Comment: Well the result $\int_\infty^\infty f(x)~\mathrm dx$ is certainly meaningless. That is like saying $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^{n+1}\frac1x~\mathrm dx=\int_\infty^\infty\frac1x~\mathrm dx$$It certainly makes no sense.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt that the problem, since both the limits of integration were $N$, and that $N \to \infty$. But yeah, that wasn't correct way of approaching problem.

Comment: But it can certainly be made more correct. For example, in the case of the example I gave above, note that $\frac1x$ is decreasing and positive, hence$$0\le\int_n^{n+1}\frac1x~\mathrm dx\le\int_n^{n+1}\frac1n~\mathrm dx=\frac1n\to0$$Can you manage to find a way to squeeze your integral? There are two solutions below, and one of them follows the same idea as I've laid out in the above (hint: $xe^{-x^{2017}}$ is eventually decreasing and always positive)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt as hint given by you, $xe^{-x^{2017}}$ is decreasing and positive, $0\le lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{N}^{e^N} xe^{-x^{2017}} dx$, below Robert showed that it is $\le (N+1)e^{-N}$. And since $(N+1)e^{-N} \to 0$. By squeeze theorem limit is equal to $0$.

Comment: Well my hint actually leads to MV's answer. Can you see why? (hint: $\int_a^bf(x)~\mathrm dx\le\int_a^bf(a)~\mathrm dx$ if $f(x)$ is decreasing)

Comment: Yes, since $f(x)\le f(a)$ if $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  $ \int_N^{e^N} Ne^{-N^{2016}} dx = (e^N-N)Ne^{-N^{2016}}$ ?

Comment: Yup, that's right. Then you can prove it goes to zero.

Comment: See also: [Limit $I = \lim_{n \to\infty} \int_{n}^{e^n} xe^{-x^{2016}} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2163306) and [Does the following limit exist, and if it does what is the value: $\lim_{N \to \infty}\int_{N}^{e^N} xe^{-x^{2016}} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2225964).

Comment: BTW I found the above links using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7BN%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cint_%7BN%7D%5E%7Be%5EN%7D%20xe%5E%7B-x%5E%7B2017%7D%7Ddx%24&p=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $N>1$,
$$0<\int_{N}^{e^N} xe^{-x^{2017}}dx< \int_{N}^{+\infty} xe^{-x^{2017}}dx\leq \int_{N}^{+\infty} xe^{-x}dx=(N+1)e^{-N}$$
then use the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: @VK Singh Any further doubt?

Comment: is there any way other than L'Hospital to show $(N + 1)e^{-N}$ tends to $0$ as $N \to \infty$?

Comment: @VK Singh Yes, show by induction that for $N\geq 3$, $e^{N/2}\geq N+1$ then $0<(N+1)e^{-N}\leq e^{-N/2}\to 0$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

$$\left|\int_N^{e^N}xe^{-x^{2017}}\,dx\right|\le (e^N-N)e^Ne^{-N^{2017}}$$